# friendly URLS Login page postback

Tags: asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2013, friendly-url

**Problem**

I'm working on the loginscreen of my website. I used my own template but added the "RequiredFieldValidator" for my password and username. When I click the ASP:Button without filling in the textboxes. The RequiredFieldValidator errormessages appears for 1 second but then the page refreshes.

**Platforms**

- Firefox
- Chrome
- Opera

**My thoughts**
I think this has to do with the friendly urls nuget. I didn't touch this but when I click the login button and look at the networkevents (in Chrome - F12) I see that it's /Account/Login?.......... so without the '.aspx'

**HTML-Code**

```
<form role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group login-input">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="LoginUserName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"/>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="LoginUserName"
            CssClass="text-danger" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." />
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group login-input">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="LoginPassword" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="LoginPassword"
            CssClass="text-danger" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The password field is required." />
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input runat="server" id="InputRememberMe" type="checkbox">
            Remember me
        </label>

    </div>
    <div class="input-group login-input">
        <asp:Button runat="server" onclick="LogIn" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" Text="Login" />
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ErrorMessage" Visible="false">
            <p class="text-danger">
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="FailureText" />
            </p>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <a href="Register.aspx" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Create Account</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Password Recovery</a>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

**C# Code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Register";
    //OpenAuthLogin.ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
    //var returnUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
    //if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
    //{
    //  RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl += "?ReturnUrl=" + returnUrl;
    //}
}

protected void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValid)
    {
        // Validate the user password
        var manager = new UserManager();
        ApplicationUser user = manager.Find(LoginUserName.Text, LoginPassword.Text);
        if (user != null)
        {
            IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, user, InputRememberMe.Checked);
            IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
        }
        else
        {
            FailureText.Text = "Invalid username or password.";
            ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "*page refreshes*" do you mean there is a postback? Does the error message disappear after the refresh?

Comment: Yes, there is a postback but the messages disappear :(

Comment: That's weird, it's like the model state is being cleared (or not being saved at all). I have seen issues in the past like this fixed using a [ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424(v=vs.100).aspx). You might also want to have a look at [enabling unobtrusive validation](http://jupaol.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/enabling-unobtrusive-validation-from.html) to avoid the unnecessary postback.

Comment: The thing is when I make a new webforms project and I run the login, page it works. I made this page using the templatelogin. I'll take a look at the validationgroup!

Comment: I'm not familiar with ApplicationUser, nor do I use the requiredFieldValidator anymore, but have you checked your IsValid variable to make sure it is returning false? Perhaps the field validator is detecting the incorrect format and displaying the message, but is not stopping the propagation of the event--or not returning the proper value to your code-behind.

Comment: I used a breakpoint to check the isvalid value. When I run the website and click on the button, it doesn't break.. so indeed maybe it's a problem with the event.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. I had a form tag in my masterpage but also in my login page which gives a warning. This blocked everything...